# Why is there difference between image of iPhone camera and Image taken by my app in React Native

Tags: android, ios, iphone, react-native, react-native-camera

I am using `react-native-camera` library for implementing camera and taking images.

I have noticed that the images taken by default camera of iPhone are better in colors and sharpness than the ones I take using my app.

Also is there a way to control/access stabilisation feature of camera in react-native?

Answer (score 0):

Are you specifying a high quality of **1** from the take image options in the app? take a look at the takePicture function here [react-native-camera](https://github.com/react-native-camera/react-native-camera/blob/master/docs/RNCamera.md).

Comment: yes I am, but color correction does not seems perfect